# How can I get digest with android?

Tags: java, android, security, private-key, sign

I need to sign a `String` and send both. I have a `.pem` file as private key, and I'm trying to convert this file into a `PrivateKey`.

This is my code:

```
try {
            File privateKeyFile = new File("path to .pem file");

            //TODO: HOW CAN I CONVERT THAT FILE INTO PRIVATE KEY?

            Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
            signature.initSign(privateKey);
            signature.update(data.getBytes());

            byte[] sign = signature.sign();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | SignatureException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Have you any suggestion to give me about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved in this way:
Instead used a `.pem` file I saved directly the `String` obtained from `PrivateKey` and then when I need to sign datas, I get that `String` and the convert it into `PrivateKey`.

This is my code:

```
public String signData(final String data, final String privateKeyString) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, InvalidKeyException, SignatureException {

        X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(privateKeyString.getBytes());
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PrivateKey privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec);


        Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
        signature.initSign(privateKey);
        signature.update(data.getBytes());
        byte[] sign = signature.sign();
        return new String(sign);
    }
```